# Real-time Scraper | Complicated Issue

Tags: python, excel, scrapy, automatic-updates

I have an up and running webscraper; the tickers are listed on a separate excel document. I am using ScrapingHub's API because it is accessible anywhere, and provides a big convenient factor. I want to create a code that will update and scrape from what is listed on the Excel sheet.

With my excel list, how can I have my code automatically update (ie. I add MSFT to my excel sheet so this updates my code to include MSFT)?

Additionally, is there anyway to have it automatically deploy?

--==Spider Code==--
**tickers appended in each link (search criteria)

```
import scrapy
import collections

from collections import OrderedDict
from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider
from tickers.items import tickersItem
class Spider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = "NewsScraper"
    allowed_domains = ["yahoo.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=ABIO,ACFN,AEMD,AEZS,AITB',
        'https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=BGMD,BIOA',
        'https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=CANF,CBIO,CCCR',
        'https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=DRIO,DRWI,DXTR,ENCR',
        'https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=GNMX,GNUS,GPL,HIPP,HSGX',
        'https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=MBOT,MBVX',
        'https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=NBY,NNVC,NTRP',
        'https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=PGRX,PLXP',
        'https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=SANW,SBOT,SCON,SCYX',
        'https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=UNXL,UQM,URRE',
                  )
    itertag = 'item'
    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        item = collections.OrderedDict()
        item['Title'] = node.xpath(
            'title/text()').extract_first()
        item['PublishDate'] = node.xpath(
            'pubDate/text()').extract_first()
        item['Description'] = node.xpath(
            'description/text()').extract_first()      
        item['Link'] = node.xpath(
            'link/text()').extract_first()
        return item
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. What works and what does not work with your current solution?

Comment: Hey Paul! I've updated my post to make it a bit more clear as to what I am trying to achieve. 

I essentially want my scraper to be able to reference the list of ticker symbols that I have on the sheet.